# Microsoft Edge on Linux

Tags: wine, microsoft, ie

I'm a web developer and need Microsoft Edge for testing on my Ubuntu.

I know I can have Microsoft Edge by:

1. Installing Windows on Virtual Machine.
2. Linux - Windows Dual boot.

But with these solutions, I have to buy Windows while I'm not using it for everyday computing. Also I can't get rid of the Windows with these solutions.

I've read some articles about Microsoft Edge on Linux but couldn't find any solution. In 2015 they did this conference and Edge on Linux still doesn't happening:

[WOAH, I CAN TEST EDGE & IE ON A MAC & LINUX!](http://blog.reybango.com/2015/05/15/woah-i-can-test-edge-ie-on-a-mac-linux/)

I also found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/is-the-edge-browser-available-for-linux-based/27083ca8-c7b5-4610-ab60-84f508caeccc) and It seems Microsoft doesn't care for Edge on Linux. at least for now:

> It turns out that Microsoft Edge is only available with operating
> system like Windows 10 and a browser application with few mobile
> devices.

Is there anyway to have Microsoft Edge on Linux without VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In November 2021, Microsoft announced in [their blog](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/11/02/edge-ignite-nov-2021/) that the stable version of Microsoft Edge can be installed in Linux devices.

> Last October, we made Microsoft Edge available on Linux in preview channels (Dev and Beta channels) and today, the browser is generally available for Linux via the stable channel. This milestone officially rounds out the full complement of major platforms served by Microsoft Edge through stable channel: Windows, Mac, iOS, Android, and now Linux. To use Microsoft Edge on Linux, users [can download it from our website](https://www.microsoft.com/edge/business/download) or retrieve it using the command line from a Linux package manager.

You can download the .deb file from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/edge/business/download) and then follow the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769542) to install the software.

Note this:

> Installing Microsoft Edge will add the Microsoft repository so your system will automatically keep Microsoft Edge up to date.

Answer (score 32):

First, install VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Then, install the Edge virtual machine for VirtualBox from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Comment: Note that this is free and should have been the accepted answer as the linux version is not identical to the windows one and the Edge user base is Windows.

Answer (score 16):

**Microsoft Edge for Linux** is now available in the Beta and Dev Channels at [Microsoft Edge Insider Channels](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/?platform=linux). Packages are available in `deb` and `rpm` formats.

Files can also be downloaded from the Microsoft package repositories: [DEB](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/), [RPM](https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/edge/)

To examine files before installation:

```
mkdir /tmp/msedge
dpkg-deb -x microsoft-edge-dev_93.0.957.0-1_amd64.deb /tmp/msedge
```

After extraction, it's possible to run without installing:

```
/tmp/msedge/opt/microsoft/msedge-dev/microsoft-edge-dev
```

**Warnings**

- If the `deb` is installed, it will add an apt repository by creating `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list`.  This behavior is inherited from Google Chrome.
- The EULA states the following:

  > If you disable data collection through controls available in the Previews, we may continue to collect diagnostic information about the download, the installation and any removal of the Previews and “basic” data as described in the Windows Diagnostics section of the [Microsoft Privacy Statement](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement).

**Note:** This answer [previously](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1166474/8) contained a tutorial about installing Microsoft Edge on WINE. This seems to no longer be possible as a result of changes in the installer, WINE, or both.

Answer (score 14):

**Update 2022**

Microsoft Edge is available on [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.microsoft.Edge) and since it is a Chromium based browser, you can use any of the available Chromium based browsers to test (for web development) and the result should be the same.

**Update 2018**

Microsoft announced that Edge will be released with Blink engine (Chromium) in early 2019. They didn't talk about Linux version yet and at this point only VM and Browserstack works.

> Microsoft Edge will now be delivered and updated for all supported versions of Windows and on a more frequent cadence. We also expect this work to enable us to bring Microsoft Edge to other platforms like macOS. Improving the web-platform experience for both end users and developers requires that the web platform and the browser be consistently available to as many devices as possible.

**Browserstack**

With [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-microsoft-edge-browser) there isn't any need for VM or Dual boot. It shows Microsoft Edge on any browser. [It will allow to test your local sites](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing).

> Till now, developers have been relying on virtual machines or PC’s with Windows 10 to test their products and websites on Microsoft Edge. To provide an easier way to test, Microsoft and BrowserStack are partnering to give developers a cloud based infrastructure to instantly test and ship great experiences on Microsoft Edge.

and about [Local Testing Security](https://www.browserstack.com/security):

> Local Testing enables you to test local folders and internal servers. We use custom-designed Chrome and Firefox extensions, with WSS (secure WebSockets) to connect your machine to the cloud. WebSockets allows extensive interaction between the client browser and the servers and devices. To protect the privacy of transferred data during the testing session, we use WSS exclusively. WSS uses SSL over port 443 for transport and therefore only transmits encrypted data.
>
> When testing an private server, we forge a connection between the server you have specified, and our virtual machines or physical devices. The mechanism is set up to forward requests and responses back and forth, and nothing else. Similarly for local folder testing, the BrowserStack cloud only has access to the folder mentioned during the setup of the connection. Our infrastructure cannot access anything else on your filesystem.

Comment: Websites are not images, interaction needs to be tested too.

Comment: Timo, Browserstack has live testing if you didn't know...

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Edge for Linux is now in Beta. Read this article for more information: https://www.techradar.com/news/microsoft-edge-for-linux-gets-an-official-beta-release

To install Microsoft Edge from the Beta follow these steps:

(Do note that **installing Microsoft Edge, (using the following methods), will add the Microsoft repository so your system will automatically keep Microsoft Edge up to date.**)

### Method 1

1. Go to https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/?platform=linux-deb.
2. Click on *Download* under the Beta Channel.

   [image: Screenshot of a portion of https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/]
3. Read the license terms and then press *Accept and download*.

   [image: Screenshot of a portion of https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/ after clicking on Download under the Beta Channel]
4. A dialogue box might appear in Firefox depending upon the settings. Choose Save File and click OK.

   [image: Screenshot of dialogue box in Firefox]
5. Open the folder where the .deb file is saved. Right click (not on the file) and choose Open in Terminal.

   [image: Screenshot of right-click options in Nautilus]
6. Now the terminal will open. Execute the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./microsoft-edge-beta_92.0.902.15-1_amd64.deb
   ```

   **Note**: The file name may vary. Please use the name of the file which you have downloaded.

---

### Method 2

[image: Screenshot from https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/?platform=linux-deb]
Screenshot from https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/?platform=linux-deb

1. Open Terminal. Execute:

   ```
   curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
   ```

   If `curl` is not installed, run `sudo apt install curl` and then run the above command.
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-beta.list'
   ```
4. Run:

   ```
   sudo rm microsoft.gpg
   ```
5. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
6. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt install microsoft-edge-beta
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the [free virtual machines](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) (that expire after 90 days) Paul posted, you can also use other useful tools like [BrowserStack](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/remote/).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft announced that Edge will abandon it's curent engine to become another Chromium based web-browser. (Like we hadn't enough of those already !) So in the future you won't need to test with Edge as long as you do it with any other Chromium based browser.

Comment: How does this solve op's **current** problem? Rather than solving the issue some time in the future?

Comment: @j-money You're right, it doesn't solve anything NOW, but it still seemed important to me. 

That said, and while a bit unrelated, I find it sad (and a bit dangerous) to have almost all web-browser use the same engine. I would have preferred if Microsoft add chosen to open the code of their render engine instead.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge is available to download as a Dev preview channel at https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com

Everything seems working fine except the `sign-in / sync`. (Currently, it supports Windows 10 version 1709 and above, and macOS version 10.12 and above.)

Answer (score -5):

No, you can not get Microsoft Edge on Linux/Ubuntu or any other Linux machine. Instead of using Microsoft Edge try using a text editor that comes with your system. A text editor should function almost as well as Microsoft Edge for programming (By the way, I'm a web developer too).

Comment: I want to see how Edge and IE show and handle my html/css and javascript. How text editor can do what these browsers do?

Comment: @ICE Use a VM, and/or use RemoteIE.