# Watching Amazon Prime video HD on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: video-streaming, amazon

I think it has been known for a good while that Amazon Prime Video is SD only on system running anything other than Windows and MAC:
https://www.primevideo.com/help?nodeId=GUX9FYHU5D8LC9EJ

Is there a way to work around this limit?
It'd be a shame having to use a virtual machine running Windows (if it even works) to just watch Prime video.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=248180), the following solution *might* work:

1) Install `winehq-staging`

2) Install Edge-dev: see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840987/microsoft-edge-on-linux)

3) Run Edge:

`wine 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe'`

4) Log in to amazon prime video using your newly installed MS Edge browser and HD could work

Let me know if this works....

Comment: Thanks for the instruction, I have also heard that wine works, but I haven't tried. I will give it a shot. Though, I really hope there is a more Linux way to solve it without turning back to a MS browser.

Comment: @Sandbo Unfortunately this is Amazon's fault, not the linux developers. Reaching out to the Amazon Prime Video support staff and complaining about this issue could help..

Comment: I fully understand, but I have seen there are already quite a lot of users having complained to Amazon. If they were to take any actions there would have been some. I could try to add my voice but likely they will leave out the small Linux desktop community after all.

Comment: didn't work for me.

Comment: @HerpesFreeEngineer Did you get edge running correctly with WINE and when you went to Prime Video it didn't show in HD?

Comment: This no longer works 

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching a solution for a while, and this method once worked for me:

1. Install Wine staging version 6.4 with `sudo apt install winehq-staging=6.4`

2. Download Chrome 86.0.4240.75 Official build 64-bit Portable (can be found here: https://www.filepuma.com/download/google_chrome_64bit_86.0.4240.75-26781/) and run the .exe with wine
3. Access and log in in Prime Video and the HD streaming should work