# Microsoft Edge installer is provided as .rpm. How can I install it on Ubuntu?

Tags: deb, convert, rpm

For my work I need Edge browser. However, in the Microsoft web site they provide it as an `.rpm` file. To install in Ubuntu it needs to be converted to a `.deb` file.

I tried to convert it, but failed. Can anyone convert it and provide it?

Herewith I is the link of the `.rpm` file:

https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download?platform=linux-deb

Comment: Click the link directly, don't open the dropdown menu, then it will download the `.deb`-file. I just tried, the link you provided works. When you look at the dropdown menu it says "also available"...

Comment: See [Random Person's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346117/618353) specifically.

Comment: Try this command: `wget https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/microsoft-edge-beta/microsoft-edge-beta_93.0.961.27-1_amd64.deb -P ~/Downloads`. The .deb file will be downloaded in your Downloads folder after the command runs successfully. Credits to [BeastOfCaerbannog](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58992564#58992564).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the download link for `microsoft-edge-beta_93.0.961.27-1_amd64.deb`:

https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/microsoft-edge-beta/microsoft-edge-beta_93.0.961.27-1_amd64.deb